# I am trying to have a random character to be generated in a two d array once so that i can guess where the char is in the array

Tags: java, arrays

Can you help me write a code that randomly generate a char so that the user can select the location of the array and guess where the generated character is?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Array2d {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Random rand = new Random;
        char [][] set = new char [2][4];

        for(int i = 0; i < set.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j <set[i].length; j++)
            {
                char space = 'p';
                //set[i][j] = space.rand;

                //need to generate a char in the array and display it 
                //so that i can find the char in the 
            }
        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to find 'p' in current array of chars?

Answer (score 0):

dear your question is unclear,do you hav a problem in getting randm charactr?

simply put the characters in an array and generate random number between 0-25 and get the character placed at that randomly generated index.

```
string s[]={a,b,c,d...,z};
int a = (int)(Math.random()*26);
char x = s[a]; // you have random character in x
```